# Type of arrows wxmaxima

Tags: vector, maxima, wxmaxima

How can I change the size and type of arrows in wxmaxima?

```
draw2d(
    xrange=[0,2],
    yrange=[0,3],
    vector([0,0],[1,1])
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use options head_length, head_type and head_angle. Check the possible values in Maxima's help.